# How can I assign a static IP to just one device on my home network?

Tags: dhcp, static-ip

**EDIT: just found the answer myself by looking under 'Address Reservation'**

I want to assign a static IP to my Android phone on my home network.

The other devices (iPads, other computers, etc), I don't need to assign anything to them. I just want to assign it to my phone as I run a program on it that is found by a hardcoded IP address.

My router is a Netgear WNDR3800 and currently it uses DHCP to assign IP addresses.

Can I use DHCP and static IP addresses together?

Comment: oops...just went and checked my router and saw address reservation and added it there. Should have checked before posting...sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign static ip to your device, just make sure its not in the dhcp range, as to avoid ip conflicts on your network. Your use of the dhcp reservations, works just as well if you can reserve an ip for a specified mac address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your router off hand, but many support static IP allocation (ie you define a host by MAC address to have a specific IP served).

I do this at my home and leave all my machines dynamic but the router assigns static vars. So I can access devices as needed.